# How to find duplicate record in Employee table without knowing Employee ID

Tags: java

```
emp_id  emp_name emp_age
------------------------
001  -  Amar   - 23
------------------------
002  -Amarjeet - 24
------------------------
001  - kumar   - 25
```

---

Comment: This functionality is provided by Master data management (`MDM`) solutions. I don't think there is any free solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT emp_id  FROM EMPTable 
GROUP BY emp_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```